# Raspberry Pi Router: NAT & iptables --to-destination is not recognized

Tags: iptables

I'm struggling to get NAT working on my Raspberry Pi as I intend.

Without giving a lot of information, this is the issue I encounter

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlan0 --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.241:22
iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): unknown option "--to"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I believe this is supposed to map any incoming connection on port 2222, protocol tcp, interfact wlan0 to the ip address and port 192.168.2.241:22.

However I get this error that the switch `--to` is not recognized.

I also tried using `--to-destination` however that also fails.

Is this due to some new update with Raspbian / Debian 10?

Comment: The message is basically telling you to look and the iptables manual. According to the manual, there is no --to option. or --to-destination option. Try -d or --destination. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html

Comment: @paul hi and thanks for the reply, I did actually have a good look in detail at the man pages on my system, but it seems I was confused by reading several different documenations online! I did not realize that `-d` was the ame as `--to-destination` - cheers & all the best!

Comment: @Paul Actually I'm not sure if my above comment is correct. I had another look into this and I assumed that `-d` should be changed to `-s` (source) and that `--to-destination` should be changed to `-d` - but looking again I'm not sure this is the case, since there seems to be no way to specify port translation with these options? Apparenly my `iptables` is `v1.8.2`. A lot of online documentation refers to `--to-destination` as an option, which isn't available in `v1.8.2`, apparently. Any idea why this might be?